# Meaning for `survived its reign...`

Tags: meaning

The context of this part of text is `Chaos`:
Prophets foretell if its coming... Historians record its passing.
And the only ones who can fully understand it are those `who have survived its reign`...

Could you please explain the phrase `who have survived its reign...`

I understand it in this way: The chaos conquered on the planet, and somewhere ages hence after it has gone, people who survived are the only ones who can fully understand it.

Comment: The reign of a sovereign is the time that person is in power. Here chaos is personified as a king. Only those who fully understand chaos can survive against its destructive power.

Comment: @user105719, but the action is in `past` and the only ones who understand it at this point in time are survivors... because they survived its reign. Don't they?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I seem to be missing the point of confusion. Yes, the action (the reign of chaos) is in the past even though the verbs are present tense (*foretell*, *record*, *can understand*). Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current understanding is correct. 'Those who have survived' refers to everyone who was alive during the chaos who still was alive after the chaos.